# TS: Error: Cannot find module (modifying tsconfig does not help)

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am using [this library](https://github.com/metaplex/js) in my project and something really weird is going on.

This import works:

```
import {Account} from '@metaplex/js';
```

While this fails:

```
import {Edition} from "@metaplex/js/lib/programs/metadata";
```

The error I get is:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@metaplex/js/lib/programs/metadata/accounts/Edition'
Require stack:
- /Users/ilmoi/Dropbox/crypto_bc/sol/nft-armory-node/index.ts
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename.sharedData.moduleResolveFilenameHook.installedValue [as _resolveFilename] (/Users/ilmoi/Dropbox/crypto_bc/sol/nft-armory-node/node_modules/@cspotcode/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:679:30)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ilmoi/Dropbox/crypto_bc/sol/nft-armory-node/index.ts:8:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/ilmoi/Dropbox/crypto_bc/sol/nft-armory-node/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1371:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/ilmoi/Dropbox/crypto_bc/sol/nft-armory-node/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1374:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/Users/ilmoi/Dropbox/crypto_bc/sol/nft-armory-node/index.ts' ]
}
```

What's even weirder is that my IDE can easily track down the module and doesn't throw any errors.

All the advice online that I was able to find is about changing tsconfig to `commonjs` or setting `"moduleResolution": "node"` - but I've long done that and no luck.

My tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

Any advice would be

Comment: You are trying to import an `.d.ts` file, that contains declarations only

Comment: hm do you know which setting in tsconfig is responsible for determening whether actual code or just declarations are exported? this might be a stupid question:) I'm just thinking if I can rebuild the lib so that it works as intended

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try this?

```
import { Account, programs } from '@metaplex/js';
const { metadata } = programs;

let Edition = metadata.Edition
```

Comment: so that works too, but could you explain WHY it works? Why can't I import directly like with any other library?